# Compare String to a Regex

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I was asked in a job interview to write a function that gets a string r representing a regex, and an input string s, and to say whether the two match.

The regex may contain the following symbols:

- `a-z`
- `.` match any single character
- `*` look at the previous character at the regex, and match it zero or more times. (the regexes re legal so the sequence `.*` can't appear in the regex)

The input string may contain only `a-z`

Using automata wasn't practical since I had to write the code to implement it in 30 minutes, and attempting to create an automata out of the regex would be out of scope (the interviewer said so too).

Also - due to the way * was defined, using the build in methods in java to check whether the regex matches the string aren't optional too (I assume). 
I solved it in the following manner:

```
public static boolean isMatch(String regex, String s){
    if(regex.length()==0 && s.length()==0)
        return true;

    int j=0,i=0;
    boolean match=false;
    for(;i<regex.length() && j<s.length() && !match;i++)
    {
        if(regex.charAt(i)!='.' && regex.charAt(i)!='*')
        {
            if(regex.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(j))
                return false;
            else
                j++;
        }
        else if(regex.charAt(i)=='.')
        {
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            char n=regex.charAt(i-1);
            int mone= countChar(s, n, j);
            for(int k=0;k<=mone && !match;k++)
            {
                match=isMatch(regex.substring(i+1),s.substring(j+k));
                if(match)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return match || (j==s.length() && i==regex.length());
}
```

It works but the complexity is O(n!) when n is the length of the regex.
I would like to know whether there is another, more efficient way to solve this.

Comment: You want to check if the two regular expressions are the exact same? Or are you trying to check if they produce the same results?

Comment: @VinceEmigh as far as I understand, the OP wants `s.matches(regex)` Not sure why this isn't a valid answer.

Comment: Please precisely define what "match" means. Give an example to make it clear. Do you mean `[a-z][a-z]` "matches" `[a-z]{2}`?

Comment: @JBN There must be more to it, otherwise 30 minutes would not have been allocated for the task. Perhaps using `String#matches()` was prohibited.

Comment: Unless the question was there to evaluate if the candidate tends to choose ready-made, standard, tested, fast-enough solutions, or tends to reinvent the wheel. Giving only 1 minute would have been too strong of a hint. Not saying that's what happened, or that the OP should have answered that, but maybe that was the point.

Comment: let's say that the String#matches() was prohibited. How would you solve this problem on your own?

Comment: I'm with JB Nizet: the questions seems to be asking if the interviewee knows about the `Matcher` API.  30 minutes might be the time for the whole interview and the interviewer might have had additional or follow-up questions prepared.  If the question really was "implement a regex engine in 30 minutes" they're nuts.

Comment: @markspace: They didn't ask "implement regex engine in 30 minutes"; it's a very crippled regexp syntax (only one quantifier that can only repeat a literal, no alternation, no grouping, no captures, no optionals, no escapes, no zero-width assertions, definitely no recursive matching...), which should be doable (but i'd absolutely hate doing it on paper/whiteboard).

Comment: This belongs to [codereview.se]